# Add attachements event Outlook AddIn

Tags: c#, outlook, com, ms-office, outlook-addin

I try to get the attachement file in an outlook plugin before the file attache to a the mailItem.

```
    private void Inspectors_NewInspector(Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
        {

            if (Inspector.CurrentItem is Outlook.MailItem)
            {

    Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)Inspector.CurrentItem;
                    Inspector.AttachmentSelectionChange += Inspector_AttachmentSelectionChange;
                    Application.AttachmentContextMenuDisplay += Application_AttachmentContextMenuDisplay;
                    mail.BeforeAttachmentAdd += Mail_BeforeAttachmentAdd;
                    mail.AttachmentAdd += Mail_AttachmentAdd;
                    mail.BeforeAttachmentWriteToTempFile += Mail_BeforeAttachmentWriteToTempFile;
                    mail.BeforeAttachmentSave += Mail_BeforeAttachmentSave;
}}
```

When i create a new Email in outlook, my code passe by this method, but the event is never fired when i add an attachement to my email.

Any idea ?

Comment: The answer is over here: [Event Handler not being added to new Mail Items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576890/event-handler-not-being-added-to-new-mail-items)

Comment: Wow ... your right! Thanks very much

Comment: Glad it helped ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the source object at the class level (global scope) to prevent it from dwiping by the garbage collector, for example:

```
    Outlook.MailItem mail = null;
    Outlook.Inspector inspector = null;

    private void Inspectors_NewInspector(Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
    {
        inspector = Inspector;
        object oMail = inspector.CurrentItem;
        if (oMail is Outlook.MailItem)
        {

                mail = (Outlook.MailItem)oMail.CurrentItem;               
                inspector.AttachmentSelectionChange += Inspector_AttachmentSelectionChange;
                Application.AttachmentContextMenuDisplay += Application_AttachmentContextMenuDisplay;
                mail.BeforeAttachmentAdd += Mail_BeforeAttachmentAdd;
                mail.AttachmentAdd += Mail_AttachmentAdd;
                mail.BeforeAttachmentWriteToTempFile += Mail_BeforeAttachmentWriteToTempFile;
                mail.BeforeAttachmentSave += Mail_BeforeAttachmentSave;
        }
    }
```